# Salesforce data loader error no such field

Tags: salesforce

I am trying to build an application to export and archive data from SF. I'm trying to export data from several objects, but I'm having problems with a few of them. I'm getting errors like

```
6140 [Approvals__c_Export] ERROR com.salesforce.dataloader.action.progress.NihilistProgressAdapter  - No such field deducted_ on entity Approvals__c
```

I've check and there is no such filed called 'deducted_' it's called 'Deducted_from_payment__c' and that is what the sql has as well as the mapping file.
I used the data loader gui to generate all my sql statements and they all work with the gui but if i try with the command line it fails.

I am getting the same error on other objects, and for every field it complains about there is a '_from' in the field.

I've tried putting [] around the field as well as '', with no luck.

Here is the process-conf

```
  <bean id="Approvals__c_Export" class="com.salesforce.dataloader.process.ProcessRunner" singleton="false">
<description></description>
<property name="name" value="Approvals__c_Export"/>
<property name="configOverrideMap">
  <map>
    <entry key="process.outputError" value="archive\status\Approvals__c_Export_error.csv"/>
    <entry key="process.outputSuccess" value="archive\status\Approvals__c_Export_success.csv"/>
    <entry key="sfdc.entity" value="Approvals__c"/>
    <entry key="sfdc.extractionRequestSize" value="600"/>
    <entry key="sfdc.extractionSOQL" value="Select Id, OwnerId, IsDeleted, Name, RecordTypeId, CreatedDate, CreatedById, LastModifiedDate, LastModifiedById, SystemModstamp, LastActivityDate, Department_Code__c, Customer_Account_Code__c, Business_Unit_Code__c, Notes_by_submitter__c, Approval_Status__c, A__c, Requested_by__c, Account_Customer__c, Customer_SO__c, Globe_Company__c, GL_Code__c, PO__c, PO_Amount_Before_Tax__c, PO_Number__c, Old_Vendor_Name__c, Invoice_or_email_attached__c, Total_Qty_of_PO_items__c, Total_PO_amount__c, PO_Complete_Attached__c, Record__c, P__c, Customer_Account__c, Date_Requested__c, New_Vendor_Name__c, Claim__c, Payment_Term__c, Vendor_Street__c, Vendor_City__c, Vendor_StateProvince__c, Vendor_Country__c, Vendor_ZIP_Postal_Code__c, Vendor_s_Invoice_Number__c, Invoice_Required_for_resolution__c, Return_Y_N__c, Claim_Reason__c, RMA_Invoice__c, Vendor_Number__c, Globe_Invoice__c, Vendor_Account_Number__c, Globe_Service_Requests__c, 'Deducted_from_payment__c', Invoice_Date__c, Actual_Invoice_Amount__c, Difference_between_approved_actual__c, Invoice_is_in_advise_A_P__c, New_approval_required__c, Customers_Cheque__c, SO_Number__c, Customer_Deduction__c, Purchase_Order__c, Origin__c, Defective_Allowance__c, Total_Excluding_Taxes__c, GST__c, PST__c, HST__c, BOL_attached__c, Delivery_Date_of_Goods__c, Payment_terms__c, Packing_Slip__c, Proof_of_Delivery_or_P_U_attached__c, Logistics_Reason__c, 'Notes_from_Finance__c', 'Notes_from_Logistics__c, Claim_ID__c, Store_Number__c, Return_Closing_Date__c, Blanket_Return_Check_Here__c, Reason_for_Return__c, D_C_Action__c, Condition_of_goods_prior_to_return__c, If_the_goods_are_to_be_returned_without__c, Who_will_be_paying_for_shipping__c, Number_of_Cases__c, Weight_in_Lbs_of_Return__c, Number_of_Pallets__c, Pallet_height__c, Address_of_pickup__c, Operations_Comments__c, RA_3__c, Sales_Plan__c, Goods_be_returned_in_master_loose__c, Repack_specifications__c, Cost_of_Transportation_CDN__c, Additional_Fees_CDN__c, Total_Returns_Domestic__c, Grand_Total_Domestic_Returns__c, DC_costs_estimate__c, DC_costs_estimate_Details__c, Department_Code2__c, Total_Claim_excluding_taxes__c, Claim_Reason_Other_Detailed_Description__c, GL_Reference_accepted__c, Pending__c, Sales_Comments__c, Logistics_Comments__c, Finance_Comments__c, PM_Comments__c, Corrective_Action_Request__c, CR__c, SC_Teams__c, GL_Reference_balance__c, Claim_Value_Accepted__c, Claim_Value_Balance_not_accepted__c, Tax_Schedule__c, Tax_Combined_Rate__c, Total_Claim_with_Taxes__c, Off_Invoice_Deduction_Value__c, Finance_refusal_reason__c, Date_submitted_for_approval__c FROM Approvals__c WHERE LastModifiedDate &lt; 2012-01-01T00:00:00Z"/>
    <entry key="process.operation" value="extract"/>
    <entry key="process.mappingFile" value="conf\archiveSDL\Approvals__c.sdl"/>
    <entry key="dataAccess.type" value="csvWrite"/>
    <entry key="dataAccess.name" value="archive\data\Approvals__c_Export.csv"/>
  </map>
</property>
```

Comment: Just eyeballing the SOQL I can see it's not right in that it's got a bunch of single quotes around some of the fields (and one of them has an open single quote that is never closed).  Is this really what you're running or is this the result of a failed experiment with single quotes?  Field names in Salesforce.com require neither quotes nor brackets.

Comment: It is the failed experiment that i forgot to remove. I fix the missing quote and still the same results.